# moving SD card in and out without messing up apps in it

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I always leave my SD card inside my phone, but yesterday I had to use it in a Galaxy Mini 2 to install a custom ROM.

As I put it in my own phone, all apps which where installed in the SD card where missing (**"App isn't installed"**) fortunately my data was not corrupted, but I move my SD often and I'd like to avoid this kind of problems. How can I do that?

Also, I'd like to notice that the custom CWM was buggy (in fact the samsung was bricked), but I don't believe that's the cause.

thank you in advance!
PS: I'm sure this is a copy of an older question, but I can't find anything similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you neither write what devices were involved, nor how you proceeded to "move the card", I can give just some generic information – though I think you're already aware of those facts:

Never simply "pick the card out" of the device (be it the phone, tablet, or computer). First you need to tell the system to close all files it might have opened from there: for performance reasons, they are always "cached", and only written back in intervals – so a file might be only partially written when you simply drag out the card. Preparation for a "clean remove" is done in different ways, depending on where the card is connected to:

- On Windows, it's usually called "safely remove", and found in the systray.
- On Linux, most graphical file managers offer an "eject" button.
- On Android, you find a corresponding setting in *Settings › Storage* to remove the card.
- On all systems, it's safe to remove the card when the OS is "shut down" and the device switched off :)

---

**Edit:**

When the problem remains despite of always sticking to above rules, the cause might be a different one. More than once I've read about specific combinations of device brand and card brand didn't play well together, and switching to a different card brand solved the issue. So in that case I'd recommend trying a different card. Several shops permit you to return it if it doesn't work out, so this would give you an option to try without to much (financial) risk.

Comment: So, even if my phone is off, cache persists and I should "safe remove" it (by turning it on)?

Comment: No, as I wrote: "On all systems, it's safe to remove the card when the OS is "shut down" and the device switched off". While shutting down, data is "flushed" (the caches are written) and the card safely unmounted.

Comment: Then there's no way to avoid that problem? I picked it out while it was shut down... I own an Huawei ascend g610, but I experience that with all my devices

Comment: I wouldn't say there's no way *to minimize the risk*. But when you always only picked it when the devices were shut down, the cause must be something else. Have you tried a different card (other brand)? Some combinations of card and device don't play well together (not that I've experienced this myself, but I've heard more than once that switching to a different brand made similar trouble disappear).

Answer (score 1):

you already know that apps are installed on SD Cards so it's normal not to work when SD card is removed because app files will be missing.
you can avoid this by installing your apps on internal memory